# Gps service - couldn't retrieve a location

Tags: android, gps

I am newbie. I wrote a class, that implements service and uses gps, but location allways null. All needed permissions are wrote and service is normally starting, i could bind to it, but retrieved location is allways null and it never goes in *onLocationChanged(Location location)*. Can anybody help, please?

```
public class GPSService extends Service {


    private static final String TAG = "GPS_SERVICE";
    private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
    private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 1000;
    private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 10f;
    Location currentLocation;

    private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener{

        Location mLastLocation;

        public LocationListener(String provider)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
            mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
        }

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
            if (location != null){
                mLastLocation.set(location);
                currentLocation = mLastLocation;                
            }

        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);            
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
        }

    } 


    LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[] {
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
    };


    private IBinder mBinder = new GPSServiceBinder();

    public class GPSServiceBinder extends Binder {
        public GPSService getServerInstance() {
            return GPSService.this;
        }
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);       
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    int minTime = 6000;
    float minDistance = 15;

    public void onCreate()
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
        initializeLocationManager();

        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[1]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[0]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }


    public Location getLocation()
    {   
        return currentLocation;
    }


    public void onDestroy()
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mLocationManager != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
                try {
                    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    } 


    private void initializeLocationManager() {
        Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
        if (mLocationManager == null) {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this on the emulator or on the real device? If on the emulator, have you tried going into DDMS, and manually set the GPS location? On the real device, just make sure your phone can receive GPS signals while indoor.

Comment: have you checked for similar Questions in StackOverflow, there are already many same Question with Great Answers.

Comment: Of course i've tried using a DDMS, telnet with geo fix command, and google this question - and couldn't find a solution, until have read a  Yury comment below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using emulator with 2.3 version of Android then there is a bug. I've just recently faced with it. You can install 2.3 x86 emulator in this case. It works fine.